# $M$-estimation in multivariate linear regression model in R

Tags: r, regression, model

Is there any function for $M$-estimation in multivariate linear regression model in `R`. I can estimate the $\beta$'s in my model by using the `rlm()` by rewriting the $y$-variables into one column but, I would like to use one function to get the $\beta$'s.

Comment: Of possible interest: [Link](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/robust-regression).

Comment: @Procrastinator Your link does show someone who proves examples of robust estimation in R and specifically M-estimation.  I think that qualifies as an answer to the question.  Why don't you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks for your comment. I did not post it as an answer because I do not really understand what $M$-estimation means. I did a quick search by mere curiosity and found that link.

Comment: It looks like that link gives examples of _univariate_ regression models using robust ($M$) estimation, but I think the question is about $M$-estimation for a multivariate dependent variable.

Answer (score 2):

The CRAN package `rrcov` specializes in robust estimation. The function `covMest()` gives the robust M-estimation of the covariance of a , but I could not find a specific function for multivariate regression.

If you already have a work around, you can write your own function to recode the data, call `rml()` and return the $\beta$s.

Comment: That's not going to work in one important case: from the manual: 'The default initial estimate is the Minimum Volume Ellipsoid computed with CovMve'. Suppose there are some discrete variables in the design space. MVE's gonna chocke on them. e.g. there are situations where you would really want an convex M-estimator and not a re-descending one.

Comment: @user603 Good job! It seems you looked into it deeper than I did.

Answer (score 2):

I just found what you were looking for: it's implemented in the [MNM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MNM/index.html) package. Here is a link to the [JoSS](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v43/i05/paper) paper describing it.

There is also a more complete, but somewhat older and less documented 
R package ([robeth](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robeth/)) that handles estimation of several other 
M-models.